# How to change image icons when navbar tab active and Inactive in angular

Tags: angular, navbar

when navbar link is active, It displays image `src="/images/email-images/mail_outline_black.svg"`

And I need to change image icon when navbarlink is inactive , It should display `src="/images/email-images/mail_outline_white.svg"`

In here, I have used boostrap navlink.

```
<a class="btn SearchBtn-via-email-tab" ngbNavLink>
<img class="email-image-itinerary" src="/images/email-images/mail_outline_black.svg" />Via Email</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A nbgNavlink, when is active is added the class "active" -so the links becomes some like-

```
<a class="nav-link active"...>
```

You can think about create a .css that take account this idea, but you can also use the property `activeId` of the [ngbNav](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/api) and use some like

```
<!--see the "template reference variable "nav"-->
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav">
   <!--see that you indicate, for this nav that the ngbNavItem is "1"-->
  <li [ngbNavItem]="1">
    <a class="btn SearchBtn-via-email-tab" ngbNavLink>
    <!--if the activeId is "1" one image else anotherone--> 
    <img class="email-image-itinerary" 
         [src]="nav.activeId==1?'/images/email-images/mail_outline_black.svg"':
                  '/images/email-images/mail_outline_white.svg"' />

  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

NOTE: You should put your images in the "assets" folder and use some like

```
   [src]="condition?'assets/images/....:'assets/images/...'>
```

-see that "assets" is not preceding by `/`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is with `<ng-template>` .
I would write something like that:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="nav.activeId" [ngIfElse]="noMail">
    <img src="/images/email-images/mail_outline_black.svg">
</ng-template>
    
<ng-template #noMail>
    <img src="/images/email-images/mail_outline_white.svg">
</ng-template>
```

Read more about it [here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-else-then)